MAPI not launching New Outlook as default MailTo client (C#)
I have some code that uses MAPI to launch the default email client. However, when the default MailTo client is set to New Outlook, MAPI launches the old Outlook client instead. This is causing the programme to hang/crash when used on a new machine that doesn't have old outlook installed.
I am using Outlook version 1.2024.403.300, with Client version 20240329006.06. The installed Mapi  dll is Mapi32.dll.
This seems to be a problem with MAPI itself, as when I launch MailTo directly, e.g.
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo{ FileName = @"mailto:email@address.com", UseShellExecute = true });
new outlook launches without issue. Unfortunately using MailTo directly is not an option as we need to add attachments to the email, and my understanding is that this isn't supported by MailTo.

The New Outlook does not support MAPI (by design), that is why the old Outlook launches.

Thank you - are there any workarounds or other ways of doing what I'm trying to do?

Simple MAPI that is. And no Extended MAPI either.

@rocketfinger there are no direct workaround, so you'll need to rethink the process (e.g. create the email using a web-based flow instead), or upload the attachments to a hosting server and create a mailto message with url links in the body. The best (and common) option is to convince users to keep using Outlook classic. Automating the creation of a new email with attachment is a scenario that will -not- be supported (by design), unless Microsoft decides to do a 180 on their vision for the new Outlook.
